# How do I set up Backbone Routes

Tags: backbone.js

This is the first time I am using Backbone and I seem to be stuck on the basics, so bear with me.

I just want to use Backbone for Routing, I'm currently testing it within the News section of my site but I can't get the routes to trigger the functions I want.

Here' my code:

```
var NewsRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes: {
  "*news": "init",
  "news:tmpl": "loadTemplate",

},

init: function(params) {
  //$("#main").load("/news/all");
  console.log('news called')
},

loadTemplate: function(tmpl) {
  console.log('loadTemplate function called')
}

});

var news_router = new NewsRouter;
Backbone.history.start();
```

I have this route working fine:

`mysite.dev/news/`  - console shows "news called"

`mystic.dev/news/interviews` - should call `loadTemplate()`

What am I mssing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed slash after "news" in the route for 'loadTemplate':

```
  "news/:tmpl": "loadTemplate",
```

Note that in your case router is configured only for hash-based navigation (like '#news/interviews' ). You may enable URL-based navigation by specifying additional options for 'start' method:

```
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
```

Comment: Hi Vitaliy, thanks for the post, I updated up routes to use the new provided example but it's still not firing. He's the route I'm trying to match: http://example.dev/news/interviews

Comment: @vitaly I missed the pushState: true item, adding that has fixed my issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've tested. This works.

```
var NewsRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes: {
  "news": "init",
  "news/:tmpl": "loadTemplate",

},

init: function(params) {
  //$("#main").load("/news/all");
  alert('news called');
},

loadTemplate: function(tmpl) {
  alert('loadTemplate function called: ' + tmpl);
}

});

var news_router = new NewsRouter;
Backbone.history.start();
```

Only updated below part.

```
routes: {
  "news": "init",
  "news/:tmpl": "loadTemplate",

},
```

Basically, you also need to remove `*` (asterisk) apart from missing slash as answered by @Vitaliy Fedorchenko.

Backbone code is not as complex as jQuery. It's pretty readable. So best thing is go to code and read rather than finding documentation. I don't understand regex as much, but if you see [splatParam variable](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-193%20splatParam), I think it is treating asterisk as wild match. Anyone can please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: For some reason that code does not work for me. Is there some kind of constructor I am missing or something. Do I need to wrap the code in a self invoking function? Seems like the code is good.